# Testflight build on iOS8 not installing

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight

I updated to iOS 8 yesterday and I can not install a testflight build.

It displays the dialog "do you want to install..." I tap yes, and nothing happens. I've heard that that the browser no longer closes, but the application just never shows up with no errors.

I've unregistered, registered, even signed up for testflight under a new account. Nothin'.
Others are able to install on iOS 8. And up until my upgrading, it was working fine on iOS 7.

(This is all through the browser still, not the new testflight application, btw)

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: iOS 8 betas including GM seed worked, then the final official iOS 8 does not work like your description.

Comment: Update: Suddenly it just started working. I guess the Testflight team fixed something, I surely didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just solved the issue by reset the phone to factory settings. Just be sure to enabled iCloud backup before to restore the device.

All tricks and checks by searching for a code signing issue, profile problem or test flight bug was without success.

The weird thing about the problem was, that it occurred only on one device. 5 other test devices could install the test flight build after the iOS8 update.

Comment: "Reset all settings" on the device did not work for me. Since this question/answer is more than 6 months old, I raised a new question for a similar issue I encountered with installing a TestFlight beta app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095631/apple-testflight-beta-app-wont-install

Answer (score 7):

Open the link you receive from the iOS mail app (not a 3rd party) and it will work.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I did factory reset and reinstalled my last backup, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably already done this but you'll need to make sure you download the new test flight app from the appstore too.

Answer (score 0):

Normal HTTP Distribution (without Testflight) is also not working. So it seems like a new security measure with iOS 8.

The only workaround at the moment is installation of an ipa via iTunes.

Comment: Since iOS 7.1 you have to distribute over SSL (https://). Normal distribution without SSL will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Bundle Id. Worked for me now. There is some problem with previously installed app versions.

Answer (score 0):

We've been having this issue also. Mostly, the 'install' button in the testflight email was absent or didn't work.
Rebooting the phone worked for all of our team members. No need to clear caches, reset settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Re-initializing TestFlight as described here - http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/867631-re-initializing-testflight-on-a-mobile-device- helped me on iPhone 5 iOS 8.1 with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone. It sure kept me busy for a while, and itunes support gave me the solution.

I am running TestFlight 1.0.2 (55) on my iPhone 5S with IOS 8.1.3 (12B466). I was unable to open my app for testing in TestFlight when clicking on the "Open in TestFlight" link. Apple gave me the following 2 steps that solved my issue

1. Uninstall and re-install test flight (not sure if this really did anything, but step 2 was the answer)
2. Click on the "Open in TestFlight" link from the Apple Mail app, not Gmail or something else