# Ad hoc can't be run on iPhone 5 iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, ad-hoc-distribution

So I usually work with testflight service to upload build and test it. Right now I faces with error that I can't install a build on one of my devices.

I just update iPhone 5 to iOS 8 and try install build via iTunes and testflight but it won't work.

On testflight it starts to download build and after sometime it says that can't install.
The app icon is grayed and when I click on it says 6.0+ device

Via iTunes also can't install.

So the problem also not with UDID or with profiles because I checked it and also the build work on another devices under iOS 7 and iOS 6, but iOS 8 won't work

Do I need to config something additional that we never confined using Xcode 5 and iOS 7 for iOS 8 for example?

also I found this link:

[ios 8 issue testflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923679/testflight-build-on-ios8-not-installing)

Comment: hmmm, TF is working fine for me with Xcode6.0.1 builds on both iOS8 and iO7.

Comment: @PaulCezanne but the problem not also with tf, I do installation via iTunes and it also says that initialling app, but nothing happen on device, just grayed app icon, as you can see it while app installed. So it never finish installation process. I use maverick and Xcode 6.0.1 also but as I said for example on iOS 6 but iOS 8 won't work so the problem seems not with Xcode. Also one issue I don't see Profiles cell in Settings->General on iPhone, what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Seems resetting to the factory settings help with this issue.