# Apple TestFlight (beta) app won't install

Tags: iphone, app-store, testflight, beta, ios8.3

We have been using Apple's TestFlight facility to distribute a beta version of our app for a few months now (migrated from the older TestFlight service before it was merged into the AppStore). Things worked smoothly until today. After uploading a new beta build to TestFlight, the app no longer installs on the device (iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3).

When opening TestFlight app and tapping "Install" to install the latest beta version of the app, TestFlight downloads the app, but when the installation completes, the app icon vanishes. The button in TestFlight app changes back to "Install", but tapping on it shows an alert:

> "Could not install [app name]. The app is currently downloading"

We've tried:

- Restarting the phone
- Resetting all settings on the phone (factory defaults)
- Upload a new build to TestFlight.

**This looks like an issue with iOS 8.3.** 
Installing on devices with earlier iOS version *did* succeed:

- iPhone 6, iOS 8.1.2
- iPhone 4S iOS 8.2

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?

Comment: This was eventually fixed by Apple, so you can install beta apps from TestFlight again.

Comment: When I removed the email from the list of testers and add again it works for me.

Answer (score 11):

I just **force killed the TestFlight App** and launched it again. Then I was able to download it. I'm running iOS9 on iPhone5S

Comment: This works for me iPhone 6+, iOS 10.1.1 & TestFlight 1.4.2 (2)

Answer (score 7):

Deleting the TestFlight app and reinstalling it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's look like a temporary bug in TestFlight.
It is happening now to everyone.

Comment: Is it happening to you? Which iOS version is installed on your device?

Comment: I am on iPhone 6+, iOS 8.1.2, and I have same problem. It all started yesterday, when all beta builds disappeared from iTunes Connect. Now, they are back, but still can't install on my iPhone.

Comment: I've tried on couple devices(with iOS 8.3), The last time that it was fine was yesterday..

Comment: It does not look temporary at all. It is now 29 October 2015. And It is happening to me.

Comment: 6 November 2015, happens to me as well.. Build are taking at least 12 hours to get processed. Once the test flight email comes, the app wont install on any device.

Answer (score 1):

I added a new tester, and it works. At the old does't work.

//Edited.

My steps:

1. Create new mail.
2. [Add user (technical role)](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/users_roles)
3. Check mark at internal users at my app.
4. Uncheck/Check TestFlight Beta Testing switch.
5. Open testflight through mail link.
6. Install.

Comment: I can confirm this is working. I removed myself as beta tester, added back, and now I can install. But it is a pain to go through entire process again, for 25 testers. Apple, you can do better, please.

Comment: Removing and re-adding myself as beta (internal) tester did not resolve the issue for me. Actually, after I've done that I don't see the app at all in TestFlight on iOS. I also tried adding a new beta tester and that didn't work either. TestFlight does not send the invitation email, and signing in to TestFlight with the new user does not show the app (user has no access to beta testing this app). TestFlight seems to be broken on multiple levels. Well done, Apple!

Comment: Add my steps to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it may be a simple temporary malfunction of testflight. I suggest to try waiting a few hours before doing hard tests such as regeneration of certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Simply quiting Testlfight and relaunching fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to set the flight mode for few seconds, reactivate connections and try to download again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue recently, I tried uninstalling testflight and downloading it again from the app store.

It wouldn't let me download, I turned my phone on and off and then I could download from the app store as well as testflight.

Answer (score 0):

Tested Solution:

1. Update XCode.(If new beta XCode version available then use it to upload).
   or
2. Update/Re-Install #TestFlight.
   or
3. Delete previous app build and re-install.